# Android App: Displaying a Bitmap image in an ImageView

Tags: java, android, bitmap, camera, imageview

I'm making an application that implements the Camera, and I was wondering why does the image get saved to a tiny bitmap when I take a picture?

When I press the capture button, for some reason the image gets scaled down (I need to save the image to INTERNAL memory, not external/sd card) and I end up having to scale it back up to display it in the ImageView, which obviously makes the photo a little bit more grainy than the camera preview is. Is there a better way to do this?

I want it to be similar to SnapChat, where the picture you take is displayed exactly how it looked when you took it...

Here's the main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


private static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";

public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mContext = this;

    if(checkCameraHardware(mContext)){
        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);

        // Add a listener to the Capture button
        Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // get an image from the camera
                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}

private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {


                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("img.jpg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fos.write(data);
                    fos.close();
                     return "img.jpg";
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if(result != null){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ImageDisplayActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(ImageDisplayActivity.KEY_PATH, "img.jpg");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

        }.execute();


    }
};
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
/** Create a File for saving an image or video */


}
```

And here's the Image Display Activity:

```
public class ImageDisplayActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public static final String KEY_PATH = "img.jpg";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_display);



    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String path = getIntent().getStringExtra(ImageDisplayActivity.KEY_PATH);

    try {
        java.io.FileInputStream in = this.openFileInput(path);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        ZoomInZoomOut touch = (ZoomInZoomOut)findViewById(R.id.IMAGEID);
        touch = arrangeImageView(touch);
        touch.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        in.close();
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}



private ZoomInZoomOut arrangeImageView(ZoomInZoomOut img){

    try {

        img.setRotation(90);
        img.setScaleX(2f);
        img.setScaleY(2f);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return img;
}


}
```

Comment: Are you crazy? What you think this will `img.jpg` give you actual image path? No its not. Its only image name.

Comment: @Devill, he saved the file as a private file. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29), it is right